# Combine multiple columns of different lengths into one column in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to combine columns of different lengths into one column using BASH. Here is an example input file:

```
11  1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
12  1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
13  1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
14  1 2         5 6   7 8
15  1 2               7 8
```

And my desired output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
3
5
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
```

The input data is pairs of columns as shown. Each pair is separated from another by a fixed number of spaces. Values within a pair of columns are separated by one space. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for fixed width field handling:

```
$ cat file
1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
1 2   3 4   5 6   7 8
1 2         5 6   7 8
1 2               7 8

$ cat tst.awk                          
BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=4)
        for (j=1;j<=NR;j++)
            if ( a[j,i] != " " ) 
                print a[j,i]
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
1
1
1
1
1
3
3
3
5
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, if the last column has more lines than the previous ones, the numbers are not printed out as desired. For example, [this](http://pastebin.com/v3d1Jaej) input file will output [this](http://pastebin.com/cBdqyjhp). Any fixes?

Comment: How can you tell which column a given value is in? Are the columns fixed width fields or are there tabs between the pairs of columns or what? Update your questions to show the more interesting input/output you linked in your comment and explain how to tell which fields numbers are in.

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "explain how to tell which fields numbers are in"; can you please elaborate?

Comment: In the last line of your input - how do you know that "7 8" is in the last 2 columns? Is it because there are tabs in the input separating the pairs of numbers or is it because the 7 start at the 19th character on the line or something else? Is every space in your input a single blank character? Also, update your input and expected output to show what it would look like if some 2-digit or even 3-digit numbers were present.

Comment: I posted some possible sample input in my question. Let us know if that is valid input and, if not, why not. Then update your question to show the worst case input.

Comment: It is because the 7 starts at the 19th character in this case. All the numbers in the input have the same number of digits. Every space is a single blank character. The input I provided is a simplified version of the actual inputs I am working with; the actual input contains all 4 digit numbers, but they are separated in the same fashion as the provided input. To your question in your answer, yes, pairs of integers are separated by a single space and each pair of integers is always separated by a fixed number of spaces, such as 3, from another, and an empty field is itself 3 spaces.

Comment: The sample input you posted is not a valid input; the input is organised as I have described and shown.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your posted input. Change every `1 1 1` to `4 1 4` for 4-digit input.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one more question; if the input file has a column of numbers before the actual data, what would be the new code to handle it? I have changed the question to reflect this. The first column is a two digit number and is separated from the actual data by two spaces.

Comment: Change FIELDWIDTHS to "4 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1" and start your for loops on fields at 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
awk -f ext.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is your input data file and `ext.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {
    ncols=4 # number of columns
    nspc=3  # number of spaces that separates the columns
}
{
    str=$0;
    for (i=1; i<=ncols; i++) {
        pos=match(str,/^([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/,a)
        if (pos>0) {
           b[NR,i]=a[1]
           if (NR==1) colw[i]=RLENGTH;  #assume col width are given as in first row
        }
        str=substr(str,colw[i]+1+nspc);
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1;i<=ncols;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) {
            if (b[j,i]) print b[j,i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working properly because the number of spaces that separates columns is not the same throughout. Each pair of columns are separated from another pair by 3 spaces, while numbers within a pair are separated by 1 space.

Comment: I do not understand. You say that the columns are separated by 3 spaces, but then you say that the number of spaces that separates the columns are not the same...

Comment: If you take a look at the sample input I provided, there are pairs of columns. Each pair is separated from another pair by 3 spaces. Within one pair of columns though, the columns are separated by 1 space.

Comment: The code seems to works on the sample you provided.. Please provide an example where the code does not work.